# Backbone listenTo not firing

Tags: backbone.js

I've set up a simple backbone.js app.  Everything is working, except for one particular event.

The part that is not working, is a 'this.listenTo' type of event.  I've never used these type of events before, so I'm sure it's some misunderstanding on my part.

app.js:

```
new bookView({ 
    model: bookModel
 }).render();
```

bookModel.js :

```
Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: function() {

        return { sections: new SectionCollection() 
    }

});
```

|

bookView.js :  this is where the event is not firing....

```
return Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {

        this.sections = this.model.get('sections'); 
        this.listenTo(this.sections, 'add', this.addSection);

    },

    addSection: function() {
                //never gets here....
        console.log("adding section...");
    }

});
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a missing `}` in your book model `return { sections: new SectionCollection() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is OK, [take a look at this example](http://jsfiddle.net/4hCr2/1/), in order for the event to be triggered you must do like this :

```
view.sections.add({
    name: "name"
    ...
});
```